# even dimensional manifold homotopic to a symplectic or complex manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, homotopy-theory, sg.symplectic-geometry, differential-topology

I have the following question: Let $M$ be an even dimensional Riemannian manifold. Under which conditions does there exists a homotopy to some symplectic manifold? is there any chance that such a homotopy exists even if $M$ is not symplectic? how does the homotopy look like? is it differentiable, only continous ... ? is there any chance that $M$ is homotopic to a complex manifold? Is there any reference in this direction ?

greetings 
mirta

Comment: Do you require a relation between $g$ and $\omega$ (resp. $J$)? If not, your condition that $M$ be Riemannian seems vacuous, since any $M$ is.

Comment: Yes, there is a chance that $M$ is homotopy equivalent to a complex manifold.  For example, $M$ could be given by forgetting the complex structure on a complex manifold.  What question do you really want to ask, and what sort of information do you already have?

Comment: Homotopy is an equivalence relation among *maps*.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan you are implicitly assuming M is closed, because $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ contradicts you.

Comment: Ah, so I am. ${}$

Answer (score 4):

A [result of Szabo](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1625732) implies that there are infinitely many homeomorphic but non-diffeomorphic 4-manifolds which do not admit a symplectic structure (the fact that they are homeomorphic is not explicitly stated, but follows from Freedman's classification). However, they are homeomorphic to a symplectic manifold, in fact a Kahler surface, from Freedman's classification.

Answer (score 2):

This question is discussed at length in [the very nice survey by A. Tralle.](http://www.emis.de/journals/UIAM/actamath/PDF/38-105-128.pdf) (Homotopy properties of closed symplectic manifolds).

Comment: Igor, isn't Tralle mostly concerned with the distinction between symplectic and Kaehler homotopy-types? For closed simply connected manifolds, the only obstructions to a symplectic form that I know are that the manifold should be c-symplectic (a homotopical property), almost complex (invariant under tangential homotopy-equivalence) and in 4 dimensions should satisfy Taubes's constraints (not homotopical).

Comment: @TimPerutz he seems to be concerned with both (e.g., he discusses the Thurston/Sullivan conjectures).

Comment: True, but I don't think he or anyone else has any answers to those questions (except for Seiberg-Witten obstructions in dim 4). In particular, rational homotopy theory hasn't helped us to answer them.

Comment: @TimPerutz well, the OP asks what is known, and this is what IS known (even if it is not very much :()